# Sql by hour starting at noon

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, hour

I'm currently using a select statement with one column as `DATEPART(hh, CallTime) AS Hour`
and then doing:

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, CallTime) 
ORDER BY Hour
```

This displays the hours starting at midnight and going through midnight - how would I go about having this go from noon to noon?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hh, CallTime) >=12) THEN DATEPART(hh, CallTime) - 12 ELSE DATEPART(hh, CallTime)+12 END AS hour_since_noon` should do it if I understood your question correctly.

You may want to have 2 separate fields, your original one to actually display and this one to order

Comment: That gives the hours in the correct format, but they are then still sorted from lowest to highest which results in them still being from midnight to midnight

Comment: Updated now that I got what you were trying to do